# Could directly output the expression result without using in a real collection

Tags: mongodb

Recently I'm studying mongo , and often need execute some commands in mongo shell, e.g. enter below command in command line

```
{
   $switch: {
      branches: [
         { case: { $eq: [ 0, 5 ] }, then: "equals" },
         { case: { $gt: [ 0, 5 ] }, then: "greater than" },
         { case: { $lt: [ 0, 5 ] }, then: "less than" }
      ]
   }
}
```

it almost output as my enter.

But I actually want is the evaluation result,

```
"less than"
```

Does have some manner could directly output the result in mongo shell or exist some other mongo client could support it?

Comment: These are aggregation pipeline expressions, they do not return a result though the shell but only through usage of the `.aggregate()` method.  Are you looking for a logical expression for the shell? Or do you just not understand the expression here?

Comment: *"Does have some manner could directly output the result in mongo shell or exist some other mongo client could support it?"* No. Not sure what other answer you would expect here. I think you should [read the manual.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)

Comment: I just want output the logical expression result, do not need have to use it embedded in aggregation or query operations. e.g.  $eq: [ 0, 5 ] ==> false

Comment: Yes you need to run it in an aggregation against a collection with something in it. This is not a programming language for building things. Just like SQL, you need data. Read the manual in the links given please.